# Python, excel, eval and the cardinal sins

Tags: python, security, exec, eval

Ok, so I know this has been asked before in many different threads but I find myself still trying to reduce my doubt.

I have an application that allows the user to pass a dictionary of strings and 'choose' a backend function from a library to process it.  The functions are part of a 'workflow' library and loaded by the system admin on the backend.  Available functions are stored in the backend in a manifest file.

The mechanics are such that the users send the dictionary as json to the web app and nominate which function from the library should process it.  The function is is then loaded and executed via the python exec() or eval() functions.

Before the execution, the requested function is checked against a list of available functions (whitelist) from the manifest file.

My basic question is, can whitelisting make exec() and eval safe?  Could it be made 'safer'?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it, the function is trusted by the admin and that makes it as safe as any python module you install. Just make sure that the exec part is only done on the trusted code. Here is an example where functions with the same name as their file are loaded and executed.

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

# files named the same as the function, no .py
FUNCTION_DIR = Path("/my/functions/are/here")

def run_func(name, data):
    try:
        func_namespace = {}
        exec(open(FUNCTION_DIR/name).read(), func_namespace)
        return func_namespace[name](json.dumps(data)) 
    except Exception as e:
        return "Hey, what kind of game are you playing here? " + str(e)
```

The the function is naturally whitelisted just because its in the known-safe directory.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.  In my case I use a .yaml file with a list of 'permitted' modules and functions.  To be more precise, I am running; exec('import <module>') and then eval('<module.func> mydict') where both the <module> and <func> strings are tested against the manifest.yaml before the exec/eval is called.